# Are there any simple way to animate other than by key frames

Tags: animation

I am a beginner and I know how to make animations with key frames. What are the other ways to make animation?

Comment: Please be more specific on what you want to do. [edit] your question and explain further.

Answer (score 1):

without keyframes. Can be used Scripted Expression. More depends on what you want to do.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/animation/drivers/workflow_examples.html